# Can I get number of opened tabs in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In C#, can I get the number of opened tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check [Selectors API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/cc307217.aspx) ? (maybe)

Answer (score 0):

C# *generally* runs at the server (unless you are talking about Silverlight etc), so there will be no way of knowing much about the client. Likewise, I would not expect this information to be exposed unless you are writing a browser extension / add-in. Basically, I think the short version is "no".